# knockoutjs make selectable items onclick within foreach

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am looping items within a foreach statement. On page load, by default I am selecting the first item (data-bind="css: { selected: $index() == 0 }"):

```
var viewModel = function(){
 var self = this;
 self.pattern_index = 0;
 self.select = function(data) {
  //handle click
 };
 self.makes = [
  {id:1, name: 'Northwoods Prestige'},
  {id:2, name: 'Forest Bay'},
  {id:3, name: 'Timberland'}
 ];
};
var model = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML:

```
  <div class='oTitle'><span class="label label-primary">Patterns</span></div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: makes">
      <div data-bind="css: { selected: $index() == 0 }, click: $root.select.bind($data)">xx </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.selected{background-color:red;}
```

My question is how to make other items selectable, selecting the clicked item (.selected) and removing selectable class from first item

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/diegopitt/g57qs9a7/

Comment: if i am not wrong you posted one such question yesterday i answered that (check the comments) . cheers

Comment: @supercool Seems the OP is asking a very similar series of questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926278/passing-index-and-data-as-arguments-to-function-for-click-handler

Comment: @CrimsonChris ha true via different accounts lol .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `selectedIndex` observable that can be used in the css binding to determine if a row is "selected".

*Example:* http://jsfiddle.net/Lgn4ppwo/

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: makes">
    <div data-bind="css: { selected: $index() === $root.selectedIndex() }, click: $root.select.bind($root, $index())">xx </div>
</div>
```

**View Model**

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.selectedIndex = ko.observable(0);
    this.select = function(index) {
        this.selectedIndex(index);
    };
    ...
};
```

Comment: thank you! It is working. I have one more question I need to pass $data to the function select. What are we passing in $root ? I see we are passing 2 parameters to the select function but it is expecting one which is index ...

Comment: @DiegoP You should look at how `bind` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind