# Passing $index and $data as arguments to function for click handler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am passing `$index` and `$data` to the `change_model` function. The function is expecting 2 parameters in the following order: `(index, data)`.

From the viewModel I am passing `click: $root.change_model.bind($data, $index())`. Within the function `index` prints `$data`, and `data` prints `index`: values are reversed.

```
self.change_model = function(index, data) {
  self.patternSelectedIndex(index);
  selected_door = data.file;
  create_door();
};
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: x.patterns">
    <div class="thumbnail" data-bind="css: { selected: $index() === $root.patternSelectedIndex() }">
      <img class='img model' style='width:164px;height:90px;padding:5px' data-bind="attr:{src:'images/models/' + $data.file + '.png'}, click: $root.change_model.bind($data, $index())" />
      <div class="caption">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It may help if you include a *wee* bit more code to make a full repro, which makes it easier for others to help you. Something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz2jw41s/1/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `bind` will become `this` inside your function, because Knockout is merely using [the regular `bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

You can either pass `$data` or `$root` as the first (`thisArg`) argument, or pass null or undefined, as you don't really need it since you seem to use the `self = this` idiom.

For example:

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.change_model = function (index, data) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(index);
        console.log(data);
        // Actual code here
    };

    self.x = { patterns: [{ file: 'some-file', name: 'some-name' }] };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: x.patterns">
    <button data-bind="click: $root.change_model.bind($data, $index(), $data)">Click me!</button>
    <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You never explained why the arguments seemed reversed. The click binding automatically passes the context as an argument to the bound function. This means that the third argument of the bind in your example isn't required.